# Traceback error in python

Tags: python, runtime-error, traceback

When I use the `float()` method in a program , I am getting an error. Can you please help me with that. I am using python 3.4.0a4.

This is the program:

```
import urllib.request

price = 99.99
while price > 4.74:
   page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices.html")
   text = page.read().decode("utf8")
   where = text.find('>$')
   start_of_price = where + 2
   end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
   price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])
Print("Buy!")
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/python 8.py", line 11, in <module>
    price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '!DOC'
```

Comment: You found the wrong `>$`. If you are parsing HTML, consider using a HTML parser instead, such as BeautifulSoup.

Comment: And unless you pre-defined `Print`, you will get a `NameError` at the last line because it should be `print`.  Python is case-sensitive remember.

Comment: Your sliced string, `text[start_of_price:end_of_price]` is not a number.

Comment: On another subject, it is unwise to do calculations with money with floating point numbers, they can't all be stored completely accurately by the computing, and so rounding errors can occur. Instead, you should use integers to hold the amount of pennies in an amount of money, or the Decimal module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you sliced the string of the web page at the wrong position, and the result of `text[start_of_price:end_of_price]` is `!DOC`.

This is not a valid number and can hence not be converted to a float.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact code given in Head first Programming. The link was broken and I got the output on correcting it. Thanks for your help..